# SQL subquery result in WHERE

Tags: sql, subquery, concatenation

I have a `Paths` table with columns `PathID` (unique) and `PathStr`.

I'd like to get all `PathStr` records in this table what starts with a string, came from a selected `PathID`.

In other words I'd like to get all subfolders of a folder if I know the `PathID` of the root folder.

Example table:

```
PathID | PathStr
-------+------------------------
   1   |  D:\Project1
   2   |  D:\Project1\Sub1   
   3   |  D:\Project1\Sub1\Sub11
   4   |  D:\Project2
   5   |  D:\Project2\Sub1
```

Required result if the `PathID = 1`:

```
D:\Project1
D:\Project1\Sub1
D:\Project1\Sub1\Sub11
```

My query looks like this now, but I'm stuck with the subquery at `WHERE`:

```
SELECT P.PathStr As 'Folder'
FROM Paths AS P
WHERE P.PathStr LIKE (SELECT Paths.PathStr FROM Paths WHERE Paths.PathID = 1) + "%"
```

I guess I can't simply concatenate the result of the sub-query with a string, but I don't know how can I do that, I didn't find solution with my friend google :)

The result of the sub-query is always one record.

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff unfortunatelly I don't know :/

Comment: So, does your query work or not? If not, do you get an error? Which? (You've confused quotes by the way. In standard SQL the single quote is for strings (like `'%'`) and the double quotes are for names (like `"Folder"`). The standard string concatenation operatoer is `||`, not `+`, but some DBMS (SQL Server being the most prominent) use `+`. Others still use a `CONCAT` function instead.

Comment: You don't know which DBMS you are using? You don't know whether you are working with Oracle or MySQL or SQL Server or whatever? How then do you know what oparations and functions are available and which manual or online docs to refer to? How do you connect to the database?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This is a Project Data Management software. I am a user not an admin or IT person, but I can run queries (called Reports). Unfortunatelly it has very poor documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest instead using `exists`:

```
SELECT p.PathStr as Folder
FROM Paths p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Paths p2 
              WHERE p2.PathId = 1 AND
                    p.PathStr LIKE CONCAT(p2.PathStr, '%')
             );
```

You have not tagged your database.  The standard operator for string concatenation is `||` and many databases also support a `CONCAT()` function.  The use of `+` for string concatenation is quite limited.

EDIT:

To fix the problem mentioned in the comment:

```
SELECT p.PathStr as Folder
FROM Paths p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Paths p2 
              WHERE p2.PathId = 1 AND
                    CONCAT(p.PathStr, '\') LIKE CONCAT(p2.PathStr, '\%')
             );
```

Note:  In some databases the backslash would need to be doubled so it is not an escape character.

Comment: Careful. As forpas has pointed out in their now deleted answer, `'D:\Project123\Sub1'` would be considered a subfolder of `'D:\Project1'` with such a query. You may want to make this `CONCAT(p.PathStr, '\') LIKE CONCAT(p2.PathStr, '\%')`.